# Echo success message in another page

Tags: php

I'm working on a project.

So here is the problem if I my insert query is a success i want to echo "SUCCESSFUL MESSAGE IN ANOTHER PAGE"  something like this below

```
if($class->insertreg($a,$b){
  echo header(location:successful.php);
  echo $a ; //this is the username 
  echo $b; // this is the email address
}
```

Comment: please do not scream while asking. It's not a polite behaviour

Comment: Pass argument to this next page, something like header('Location: successful.php?success=1'); and detect this in your successful.php - if ($_GET['success'] == 1) echo 'Success';

Comment: Welcome. Save in session, redirect to `successful.php`, read from session

Comment: If you have a session going in PHP, you could store your values there and output them when they are set and when you visit a specific page.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($class->insertreg($a, $b) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = [
        'username' => $a,
        'email' => $b
    ];
    header('Location: successful.php');
}
```

And on your **successful.php** you access the values in the session:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['username'] . ' | ' . $_SESSION['user']['email']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($class->insertreg($a,$b){
  header("location:successful.php?a=$a&b=$b");
}
```

However, `a` and `b` are bad names for a variable.

You can access the two variables in the `successful.php` with reading from `GET`

```
if(isset($_GET['a']) && isset($_GET['b']))
{
echo "<div>A: $a, B: $b</div>"
}
```